# how to change database timezone in lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

when insert with eloquent or query builder in lumen project, created_at is wrong and saved UTC.
I set in app.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
```

and in env

```
DB_TIMEZONE='+04:30'
```

and in env

```
APP_TIMEZONE=Asia/Tehran
```

but again created at is wrong.i think is bug of lumen.

Answer (score 1):

Add this variable to your `env` file.

```
APP_TIMEZONE=Asia/Tehran
```

After you have added the variable, run the command below.

```
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 1):

If your MySQL server uses the same time zone with PHP, add this code in **app.php**:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');
$_ENV['DB_TIMEZONE'] = date('P');
```

In this example **date function** returns **+04:30** or **+03:30** based on daylight saving time changes.